# With recursive function calls in php, echoes do not nest

Tags: php

So, I have a function that's meant to take a multi-dimensional array and print it out as a nice html drill-down navigation:

```
<?php
function html_print_r($array = [], $level=0, $pass_id = "-000"){
  $my_rand = rand();
  if (is_array($array)){
    foreach ($array as $key => $val){
      echo '<p>';
      for ($i = 0; $i < $level; $i++){
        // Some visual effect, adding pipe symbols to show depth.
        echo "&#124;";
      }
      echo '<a onclick=$' . "('#" . $key . $my_rand . "').toggle()>" . $key . "</a> [+]";
      html_print_r($val, true, $level + 1, $key . $my_rand);
      echo "</p>";
    }
  } elseif(is_object($array)) {
    html_print_r((array)$array, true, $level);
  } else{
    echo "<pre style='display:none; id='" . $pass_id . "' >" . $array . "</pre>";
  }
}
```

The problem is if I pass it an array like

```
["Item1"=> ["Item1a"=>"foo"], "Item2" => "Bar"]
```

Instead of getting a nested result like

```
"Item1" [+]
 |  "Item1a" [+]
 |  |    "foo"
"Item2"[+]
 |   "Bar"
```

I'm getting an incorrect printout more flat like

```
"Item1" [+]
    ""    
|
"Item1z" [+]
    ""
|
 "foo"
|
"Item2" [+]
    ""
|
"Bar"
```

I've looked over it a few times, and I can't quite figure out why. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: You do realize that your recursive calls include a boolean value for the second parameter where an integer `$level` is expected instead, right? Either remove the second arguments or add an additional parameter to your function definition. `true` will evaluate to `0` when treated numerically, so it's no surprise you'd get a `$level` of `0` for most of your entries.

Comment: Looking at your code in more depth, it looks like you have a number of problems. On top of incorrect recursive function arguments, you're 1. not adding `display: none` to nested `<p>` elements, 2. not adding pipe characters for your final `else` case, 3. not adding any `id` attribute to your `<p>` elements so they can be targeted for toggling in the first place, and 4. expecting your `<pre>` elements to behave in an inline fashion when they're actually block elements (i.e. they'll end up on a new line automatically).

Comment: I completely missed that 'true'. It was originally there for another variable I removed. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! You're on the right track, it just needs a little more work :)